# String manipulation challenge

Tags: ruby, algorithm

You are given N string and one of them is invalid. Every string has a weight equal to the sum of the weight of its characters. The weight of characters are representer as   follows

weight of a is 1
weight of b is 2
weight of c is 3

and so on

You can perform the following operating on the string

1. Select a string and increase its weight by 1
2. Select a string and decrease its weight by 1

Your objective is to equalize weights of all string except one(we call it invalid string) by performaing these operations any numbers of times. Find the invalid string i.e equalize all the string except the invalid string to some weight W such that number of required operations are minimum

Note

String contains only lower case letter
There is only one invalid string

Example we have 5 strings

chakshu
pekka
punk
golem
tyagi

output

pekka

Explanation

Weight of string chakshu is 3 + 8 + 1 + 11 + 18 + 8 + 20 = 71. Similarly for pekka, punk, golem & tyagi it is 44,62,52 & 62 respectively

Now consider chakshu as invalid string, operations required to equalize rest are 28
if pekka is invalid 19 operations are required
if punk is invalid we need 37 moves to equalize
SImilarly for golem & tyagi we need 27 & 37 operations
So pekka is a invalid string, as removing it requires least moves

What I have tried so far

```
t = gets.to_i

hsh = {}
('a'..'z').each_with_index{|elem, index| hsh[elem] = index + 1}

while t > 0 do 
  n = gets.to_i
  result = {}
  while n > 0 do 
    str = gets.chomp
    result[str] = str.chars.map{|d| hsh[d]}.sum
    n -= 1
  end
  puts [result.min_by{|k, v| v}].first.first
  t -= 1
end
```

But this solution pass only sample test case. When I run all the test cases it gives me wrong answer.

Comment: Define "wrong" in specific technical terms so we know where to help.

Comment: I believe you mean, "Now consider chakshu as invalid string, operations required to equalize rest are 28. If pekka is invalid....", not "...are 28 if pekka is invalid....".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum steps to make the weight of all the strings equal would be when the strings are made equal to median of the strings. The invalid string will be string which is decreases the total steps by the max amount.

So for calculating median, we calculate the weights of each string and sort it to find median. Then, we calculate the index of string which takes max no. steps to reach from median and return it as answer.

The problem in above algo occurs at when length of list of strings is even. So we also need to calculate the total no. of steps taken (excluding the steps taken by invalid string) to reach the median. So the answer out of the two strings is the one corresponding with minimum no. total steps.

This is python code for above algo. I have heavily commented if you can't understand anything just ask in comments section.

```
def get_weight(char):                     ### gets ascii value of character then 
  return ord(char)-ord('a')+1             ### subtract ascii of 'a' to get weight

def get_max_steps(weights,length,median):
  max_steps=-1                     
  max_indx=-1
  total_steps=0
  for indx in range(length):              ###  for each word
    tmp_steps=abs(weights[indx]-median)   ### calculate steps req to reach  
    total_steps+=tmp_steps                ### median weight
    if max_steps<tmp_steps:               
      max_steps=tmp_steps                 ### store the max steps required in max_steps
      max_indx=indx                       ### and index for which its required in max_indx
  return total_steps-max_steps,max_indx   ### exclude the max_steps from total steps for the invalid string

def function(words,length):
  weights=[0 for i in range(length)]      ### array to store weights of each word
  for indx in range(length):              ### for each word
    weight=0                              ### 
    for char in words[indx]:              ### calculate weight of each word 
      weight+=get_weight(char)            ### 
    weights[indx]=weight                  ### store it in the array
  sorted_weights=sorted(weights)          ### sort the array
  median=sorted_weights[length/2]         ### get median do Integer divison
  total_steps,max_indx=get_max_steps(weights,length,median)  ### calculate the total steps required to 
                                          ### reach median of weight excluding the steps for invalid string at max_ind  
  if length%2==0:                         ### if array's length is even 
    median=sorted_weights[length/2 -1]    ### get second median and do similar step as above and do Integer division here
    ntotal_steps,nmax_indx=get_max_steps(weights,length,median)  
    if ntotal_steps<total_steps:          ### if the total steps using second median is less  
      max_indx=nmax_indx                  ### then the string by this median is appropriate choice for invalid string

  return words[max_indx]                  ### return invalid string
  
tests=int(input())                        ### taking no. of test cases as input
for i in range(tests):                    ### run for-loop for tests no. of times
  length=int(input())                     ### taking array's length and array of strings 
  words=input().split()                   ### as input
  print(function(words,length))           ### printing the functions result
```

Comment: What will be the time & space complexity?

Comment: it will depend on the sum of the length of words in the word array. Let this sum be ```m```. And the length of the word array be ```n```. Then time complexity is ```O(m+ nlogn)```.

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by constucting a method that computes the weight of each string.

```
def weight(s)
  base = 'a'.ord - 1
  s.each_char.sum { |c| c.ord - base }
end
```

or

```
def weight(s)
  s.each_char.sum(&:ord) - s.size * ('a'.ord - 1)
end
```

For example,

```
arr = ["chakshu", "pekka", "punk", "golem", "tyagi"]
weights = arr.map { |s| weight(s) }
  #=> [71, 44, 62, 52, 62]
```

Next, construct a method that determines the minimum number of iterations required to equalize the weights of all but one of the strings. Suppose the equalized weight is `x`. It is easily shown that the value of `x` that minimizes the sum of the absolute deviations from `x` equals the [median of the weights](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/816/minimizing-the-sum-of-absolute-deviation-l-1-distance).

```
def steps_required(wts)
  median = wts.sort[(wts.size+1)/2]
  wts.sum { |w| (w - median).abs }
end
```

For example,

```
steps_required(weights.values_at(1,2,3,4)) #=> 28
steps_required(weights.values_at(0,2,3,4)) #=> 19
steps_required(weights.values_at(0,1,3,4)) #=> 37
steps_required(weights.values_at(0,1,2,3)) #=> 37
```

We now need only put this all together in a method that calls the methods `weight` and `steps_required` that I constructed above.

```
def find_invalid_str(arr)
  weights = arr.map { |s| weight(s) }
  all_indices = (0..arr.size-1).to_a
  i = arr.each_index.min_by do |i|
    steps_required(weights.values_at(*(all_indices-[i])))
  end
  arr[i]
end
```

```
find_invalid_str(arr)
  #=> "pekka"
```

Comment: What will be the time complexity of it?

Comment: @AniketTiwari, Right now it's about O((n^2)log(n)), where `n = arr.size`, but tomorrow I'll do an edit that will make it  O(nlog(n)). Thanks for asking.

Comment: I will wait for the n(log(n)) solution